# How do I go about creating a flyout panel with JQuery or CSS3?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

Essentially I want to be able to hover-over my links in a left vertical column and have a panel pop-out on the right. Here's a [screenshot](http://flic.kr/p/cTsG9E) of what I'm looking to achieve. Again, I'm a complete noob when it comes to JQuery, so if there's a strictly css3 way to do this, I'm all ears.

http://flic.kr/p/cTsG9E

Comment: General practice on stackoverflow is to come along with some code that you've attempted to make work and ask for help and advice from the community. You'll get on better here if you follow this practice rather than just asking people to show you what to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a way to do this with CSS3 transitions. These may not be supported by all browsers.

The easiest would be to use jQuery.

```
<a id="trigger-link">Hover Over Me</a>
. . . 
<div id="target" style="display: none">I should not be using inline styles</div>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$("#trigger-link").hover(function() {
    $("#target").show();
}, function() {
    $("#target").hide();
});
```

This is a very simple example. But it should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at jquery animation for easy cross browser animations.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/